# echo product-name in a link

Tags: plugins

I am trying to make a link that links to the wordpress url with the product name after. (http://siteurl.com/productname)

Here is what I have, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_table_product_title', '<a href="http://vividcandi.net/telescope/'$item['name']'">'View Video'</a>', $item );
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like you might only be missing the word "echo" in front of all of that `apply_filters(...` bit. So, try `echo apply_filters(...etc.` and see if that works

Comment: Didn't work. It broke the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're wanting to do this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_table_product_title', 'my_order_table_product_title', 10, 2 );

function my_order_table_product_title( $html, $item ) {
     return '<a href="' . urlencode( strtolower( 'http://vividcandi.net/telescope/' . $item['name'] ) ) . '">View Video</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. If I wanted to make the item name URL friendly (ie. replace a space with a -) or decapitalize it, would this be possible?

Comment: Please accept this as your answer if it worked for you by clicking the checkmark on the left.  As for your other question, you encode the link, please see updated answer.